# ssh with passphrase, fallback to Google Authenticator 

Tags: ssh, google-authenticator

With the introduction of [Google Authenticator](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=1037451) and the ability to [use it with ssh](http://www.mnxsolutions.com/security/two-factor-ssh-with-google-authenticator.html) I was wondering if someone has gone through a sshd_config setup which would

- first expect a key
- if this fails, fall back to an authentication with Google Authenticator

The idea being to usually connect seamlessly with a key and, usually in less friendly environments, connect with a two factor mechanism.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, I have a setup where I can `ssh` to my server using public key authentication, with a fallback to two-factor authentication with Google Authenticator + password when my private key is not available. These are the steps you can use to set it up.

### Installing Google Authenticator

My server is running Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04.1). You can install Google Authenticator using `apt`:

```
$ sudo apt install libpam-google-authenticator
```

### Configuring sshd

Open `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and add the following line at the top:

```
auth optional pam_google_authenticator.so
```

Open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and change one line. The existing line is

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

and you should change it to

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
```

### Configuring Google Authenticator for Your Account

The next step is to turn on Google Authenticator for your account. You do this by simply running:

```
$ google-authenticator
```

Make sure you run this as the user who will be making ssh connections, *not* root. Make a note of your new secret key and your emergency scratch codes. The wizard will ask you several questions to configure the security settings for your account.

### Configuring Your Mobile App

I use the Google Authenticator app for iPhone. This app has a [+] button that allows me to add a new Time Based Token using the secret key I obtained from the `google-authenticator` command on my server. It was trivial to set up. I can't help you with apps on any other platform, but I imagine the process is equally simple.

### Pulling the Trigger

The last thing you need to do is restart `sshd`.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

At this point, when you try to connect to the server when your private key is available, authentication just works. When your private key is not available, you will get a prompt for a verification code, then your account password.

### Bingo, two-factor authentication.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is very complete and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Looks great, exactly what I need. I'll follow ur instructions and give feedback afterwards.